# Unknown specifier in URL when using Django-Tagging

Tags: python, django, django-tagging

Hi I am getting the following error;

```
    error at /
    unknown specifier: ?P[
```

This is what my URLS file looks like;

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mainpage.views',
(r'^$', 'index'),
(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'post'),
(r'^projects/$', 'projects'),
(r'^about/$', 'about'),
(r'^tags/$', 'tags'),
(r'^tag/(?P[-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/$', 'with_tag'),
(r'^tag/(?P[-_A-Za-z0-9]+)/page/(?Pd+)/$', 'with_tag'),                  
(r'^comments/$', include('django.contrib.comments.urls'))
```

The two URLS with a view name of with_tag are the offending urls. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.napes.co.uk/blog/django-tagging/);

to get tagging working on my site. I am using Django-tagging 1.3.1 and Python 2.7.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong to my URLS.py file please? I am copying the tutorial by the book but there must be something different in my set up compared to the set up used in the tutorial?

Answer (score 9):

This is not related to django-tagging, it's a regex syntax error. `?P` indicates a named group, and requires a name after it: `?P<foo>`. So, either add names to your groups, or make them numbered (i.e. remove `?P` part).

Comment: After removing the ?P it now works, thank you. I will have to have a read of the documentation on named/unnamed groups. Thank you for your help Cat Plus Plus